# Linked list prints unexpected value

Tags: c++, class, object, linked-list

No matter how many references I check, I always find that my implementation is sound.
However, this piece of program does not work, I don't know why.
Please help. Thank you.
I have this class

```
class intNode
{
    int x;
    intNode * next;
    public:
        intNode();
        intNode(int y, intNode *p);
        setNode(int y, intNode *p);
        int getX();
        void setX(int y);
        void setNext(intNode *p);
        intNode* getNext();
};
```

and this class

```
class intList
{
    private:
       intNode * head;
    public:
       intList(); //sets head=NULL
       void push( int x);
       void print();
 }
```

push is as follows

```
      void intList::push(int x)
      {
        intNode *newNode;
        newNode->setX(x);
        newNode->setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
      }
```

and print is as follows

```
void intList::print()
{
    intNode *current = head;
    cout << "Printing list" << endl;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->getX() << "\t";
        current = current->getNext();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

but somehow, this piece of code in the main

```
intList l;
l.push(5);
l.print();
```

returns this weird value: 6946556

Comment: In your `intList::push` function you have a variable that is a pointer, `newNode`. ***But*** you never make it point anywhere!

Comment: You never create a node. Also, your teacher appears to be stuck in the early 90s.

Comment: *No matter how many references I check, I always find that my implementation is sound.* -- This is fundamental that a pointer must point somewhere valid before you can use it, I am surprised you're trying to write a linked list class.

Comment: What about `std::list<>` template?

Comment: Thanks for roasting, but what can I do about the pointer newNode in the push function?

Comment: @S.Toonsi -- The comment section is for comments, so you are receiving comments about your code.  Answers go in the "Answer" box.  Almost all linked list implementations in C++ shows that nodes in a linked list are allocated using `new` -- don't know if you thought doing this was not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `intList::push` it does not create a new node but uses an indeterminate pointer value for it.

The new node must be allocated:

```
void intList::push(int x) {
    head = new intNode(x, head);
}
```

You may like to compile your code with warnings enabled, because that would be a compiler warning. For `g++` use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` command line options.

Comment: @S.Toonsi Don't forget to delete the memory that you allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine your `push` method to see where you go wrong.

```
intNode *newNode;
```

You now have a variable called `newNode`, which is a pointer to `intNode`.
This pointer is currently not set to anything (what we call "uninitialized").

Trying to access an uninitialized variable (such as dereferencing it or calling a method on it) leads to [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), which is another way of saying "all bets are off" - the standard says nothing about what should happen, so your compiler can generate whatever it wants.

So when you then do:

```
newNode->setX(x);
```

you are now calling a method on the uninitialized pointer `newNode`. Anything beyond that is pretty much *irrelevant* to our inspection of the code, because the compiler can inadvertedly do any of a number of seemingly "crazy" things when it optimizes the program.

For example, your program works fine for me on `g++ 6.4.0` with `-O0`. It prints 5. This is because the compiler doesn't optimize anything, and we apparently got "lucky" and the value that `newNode` "happens to be" is actually a valid address.

However, as soon as I go to `-O1`, the program actually outputs no value at all. My suspicion is that the compiler identified that `push` results in UB on all code paths, and thus concluded that `push` must never be called, and simply didn't bother generating any assembly for the method at all. *(Note: I did **not** verify this in the assembly at this time.)*

That's just one of the crazy things that happen when undefined behavior is invoked - see the article linked above for some others. Undefined behavior should **never** happen in your code.

Now, the correct thing to do here is to allocate a *new* node and set the pointer to point to it. Initialize it with

```
intNode *newNode = new intNode();
```

, then your code looks fine. Don't forget that `new` is a heap allocation - it's your job to make sure it's `delete`d when no longer needed (when you remove the node), otherwise you'll have stray memory lying around that's not being used (a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)).

PS: If you invoke `g++` with the `-Wall` option, it will warn you about this mistake:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void intList::push(int)’:
test.cpp:30:17: warning: ‘newNode’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
 newNode->setX(x);
```

Always pay attention to compiler warnings - there's usually good reason for them!

Answer (score 1):

Treeston has a good explanation for why arbitrary wierdness is occuring here, but I don't like his suggestion to use `new`.

Your intNode *owns* the `next` pointer, and it is the *unique* owner, so you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead. Similarly intList *owns* `head`.

```
class intNode {
    friend class intList;
    int x;
    std::unique_ptr<intNode> next;
public:
    intNode();
    intNode(int _x, std::unique_ptr<intNode> _next); 
    int getX();
    intNode * getNext();
};

intNode::intNode() {}

intNode::intNode(int _x, std::unique_ptr<intNode> _next)
    : x(_x), next(std::move(_next)) {}

class intList {
    std::unique_ptr<intNode> head;
public:
    void push(int x);
    void print();
}

void intList::push(int x) {
    head = std::make_unique(x, std::move(head));
}

void intList::print()
{
    cout << "Printing list" << endl;
    for(intNode * current = head.get(); current; current = current->getNext())
    {
        cout << current->getX() << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes! By all means, in an actual application, that is what you'd do. However, LL implementations as an exercise are typically meant to also teach about basic memory management concepts, so I expect that the teacher would want students to use `new` and learn about memory leaks.

Comment: I would prefer a teacher that teaches students to **not** use `new`

Comment: You'd then ultimately move on to teach students to refrain from it, yes. However, before you can explain to them why they should use STL pointer wrappers, they first need to understand what their purpose is (by understanding what memory management does).